# Retrievieng user data withe stormpath/laravel

Tags: laravel, stormpath

I am trying to retrieve user data in a Laravel app in which the user management is handled by Stormpath.

The `app('stormpath.user')` is outputting this (by a print_r), How can get the users email for example ?

view-source: https://blooming-ocean-84816.herokuapp.com/email

Comment: Instead of linking, can you edit and include the relevant code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Mamadou,

I was unable to see your code, if you could please, edit your post to include the actual code and output that you are seeing.  I believe I understand what you are talking about without seeing it, see below, however, if I misunderstood please let me know.

All properties are available off of the `app('stormpath.user')` call the same way they would be with using the `Stormpath\Resource\Account` class.  This is because `app('stormpath.user')` is basically an alias for the resource class from the Stormpath SDK package.

In order to get the details from the user account, you have the following available to you and more.

```
$user = app('stormpath.user');

$user->givenName;
$user->surname;
$user->fullName;
$user->email;
$user->username;
```

For some information on what is available to you, please see the SDK documentation for the Account object  http://docs.stormpath.com/php/product-guide/latest/accnt_mgmt.html#how-to-store-accounts-in-stormpath